# Collapse Borders on Specific td class

Tags: css, class, border, html-table, spacing

Take a look at this login screen:

https://www.moorefamilyhistory.net/login.php

I am trying to remove the white cell boders on all powder blue cells inside the login box (td class="tableb").  I learned about border-collapse: collapse; here on stackoverflow and tried that.  Problem is that this removes cell borders on all tables across the system which doesn't look good.  I tried using border-collapse: collapse; on "tableb" alone.  But it had no effect and subsequent reading leads me to believe that you cannot use border-collapse: collapse; on anything but the entire table.  In the course of that reading I've tried to glean something that would give me an idea of what to try next.  But nothing has popped up.

Here is my style sheet:

http://www.mconchicago.com/fsa/style.css

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the cellspacing from the whole table so it would look like this:

```
table class="maintable " width="100%" cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0">
```

Then add a border or spacing to the td's that you do want to have a white line on.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  The problem is that this is the only thing that looks out of sorts.  "Blanking out" the entire system and then adding citations where they are needed would take quite a bit of time.

Comment: Choosing this as best answer.  Judging by the lack of comments it would seem there is no other work around.